# getURLContent in RCurl still doesn't allow me to delimit data from the web

Tags: r, download, rcurl

I am writing an R script for a project that uses a data set available online. Initially I tried the following:

```
url <- "http://cssb2.biology.gatech.edu/pocketome/pdb_120518_all_het.lpc.sel.c0.9.len10.lst2"
pp <- read.delim(url)
```

Which returned the error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open: HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

After looking for answers online, I came across the option to use RCurl:

```
pp <- getURLContent(url, verbose = TRUE, useragent = getOption("HTTPUserAgent"))
```

However, when I try to delimit or scan, or any sort of action on `pp` I get the following error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file
```

Additional information:

```
> class(pp)
[1] "character"
> attr(pp, "Content-Type")
                  charset 
"text/plain"      "UTF-8"
```

To be completely honest, I've never worked with RCurl before, and I'm just trying now to figure out what it is / does / can do. I found the advice to use it from: 
`http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/File-Downloading-Problem-td3022137.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the more modern `httr`:

```
library(httr)

resp <- GET("http://cssb2.biology.gatech.edu/pocketome/pdb_120518_all_het.lpc.sel.c0.9.len10.lst2",
            user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.13+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2"))

read.table(text=content(resp, as="text"), sep=",", header=TRUE, skip=2)
```